# Allow some url in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am using below regular expression to hide website url and it's working great.

```
$message_text=preg_replace("/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/", "&#60;website hidden&#62;", htmlspecialchars($message_text));
```

$message_text will be a long message that will contain many url's along with facebook.com or gmail.com

Now I want to allow some url's like facebook.com or google.com or http://gmail.com
I am getting trouble to modify this expression.
Please help me to sort out this problem
Thank you

Comment: Just make a check before this like: `if (!in_array($message_text, $allowed)) { //regex } else { //it's okay }`, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Its not workable for me because $message_text will be long message that will content many url along with facebook.com or gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $message_text = "sdfhsdkklsdkjj www.facebook.com www.google.com http://gmail.com";
    echo $message_text = preg_replace_callback('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/', 
        function ($match) {

            $allowed = array("www.facebook.com", "www.google.com");
            if(!in_array($match[1], $allowed))
                return "&#60;website hidden&#62;";

            return $match[1];
        }, htmlspecialchars($message_text));

?>
```

Output:

```
sdfhsdkklsdkjj www.facebook.com www.google.com <website hidden>
```

Comment: edit - I am pretty sure what he has is a long string that MAY have a URL in it. He's using preg_replace to remove those URL's. The $message_text won't be just the URL.

Comment: $message_text will be long message that will content many url along with facebook.com or gmail.com

Comment: Good job there Riz ;-)